# How to display the row number in a SWT Table

Tags: java, swt

Is it possible in SWT table to display the row number like from the screenshot without creating my own row numbering?

[image: image were taken from openoffice]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, the standard SWT table does not support row numbering.

[Eclipse Nattable](https://www.eclipse.org/nattable/) does support row numbering.